# Add a custom column in users list page

Tags: admin, users

I need to hook to the users list page.

I Need to add a checkbox column for each user to remember if they have paid or not.

Thanks for help because can’t find snippet to hook to this admin page.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should remember is that function, which will be hooked into `manage_users_custom_column` action **must have 3 parameters**, the first of which (i.e. `$val`) should be the returned value:

```
// Add custom column using 'manage_users_columns' filter
if(!function_exists('bm_utm_column')){
function bm_utm_column($columns) {
    return array_merge( $columns, 
        array('utm_source' => __('UTM source'),
            'utm_medium' => __('UTM medium')
            ) 
        );
    }
}

// Add the content from usermeta's table by using 'manage_users_custom_column' hook
if(!function_exists('bm_utm_column_value')){
   function bm_utm_column_value($val, $column_name, $user_id) {
    if ( 'utm_source' == $column_name ) {
        //Custom value
        $val = get_user_meta($user_id, 'utm_source', true);
    }
    if ( 'utm_medium' == $column_name ) {
        //Custom value
        $val = get_user_meta($user_id, 'utm_medium', true);
    }
    return $val;
   }
}
// Hook into filter
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'bm_utm_column' );
add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'bm_utm_column_value', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The users list column is filtered by `manage_users_columns`. Take a look into this simple example of how to hook into this filter:

```
// We add another column using 'manage_users_columns' filter
function my_payment_column($columns) {
    return array_merge( $columns, 
              array('payment' => __('Payment')) 
            );
}
// Now we add some content to each row by using 'manage_users_custom_column' hook
function my_payment_column_value($column_name, $user_id) {
        if ( 'payment' == $column_name ) {
            // Place to add checkbox, text field, etc.

            // If the user has paid, show it. Else, show N/A.
            if ( isset($paid) && $paid ) {
                echo __('Paid','text-domain');
            } else {
                echo __('N/A','text-domain');
            }
        }
}
// Hook into filter
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'my_payment_column' );
add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'my_payment_column_value', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
function modify_user_table( $column ) {
   $column['comments'] = 'Comments';
   return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'modify_user_table' );

function modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) { 
   global $wpdb;
   if ($column_name == 'comments') {
       $comment_count = $wpdb->get_var( wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) S total FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = %s", $user_id ) );
       return $comment_count; 
   }
   return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

For detailed explanation visit http://tekina.info/add-extra-column-user-listing-page-wordpress-admin-panel/

Comment: Please, explain what the code does in the answer itself; use external links only as reference.