# How can I add data to a custom column in the Users section of the wordpress backend?

Tags: customization, users, actions, table

**Can anyone help me with adding data to a new User table column that I added?**

In the wordpress backend, in the Users section, I added a custom column called "Last Name". Now, I'd like to add last names to that column.

I've looked at this [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160422/add-custom-column-to-users-admin-panel) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268829/add-a-custom-column-in-users-list-page), but nothing has worked.

In my functions.php file, the code below is the closest I've gotten to displaying *something* on the screen, but the problem is that it's displaying it completely outside of the users list/table (directly above it in fact)

```
function last_name_value($column_name, $user_id) {
  if ( 'lname' == $column_name ) {
    echo __('last name here','text-domain');
  }
}

add_action('manage_users_custom_column', [$this, 'last_name_value'], 10, 2);
```

A value of 10 displays 'last name here' above the User table (not where I want it obviously), but I should note that it erases all the data in 5 columns for some reason. Any number below 10 and nothing displays.

I'm sure this is really easy, right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In case you want to be fully customizable, you can use the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`manage_users_custom_column`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_users_custom_column/) is a *filter* hook, so you should use `add_filter()` and not `add_action()`. Which also means you should return the output instead of echoing it.
2. The column name is the *second* parameter and not the first one — which is the current value for the current column.

So try with:

```php
function last_name_value($output, $column_name, $user_id) {
  if ( 'lname' == $column_name ) {
    return __('last name here','text-domain');
  }
  return $output;
}

add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', [$this, 'last_name_value'], 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sally. This worked perfectly! In other words, [@Jack Johansson's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268829/add-a-custom-column-in-users-list-page) was incorrect? Jack used add_action and did not return an $output in his function.

Comment: I take it, whenever we use a filter, we HAVE to return *something* in our function? And so $output has to be included as well? I looked at [add_filter here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) but it's not clear to me how the callback function works. More specifically, the arguments (like $output, $column_name, etc). I haven't been able to find documentation for this. If you can refer me to a resource that talks more about how to construct a callback function like my "last_name_value" fn, please let me know. Thank you so much, Sally :)

Comment: Hey @sansae :) Sorry, quite busy lately -_- So back then (in 2017),Jack's answer was probably correct and `add_action()` does actually work on filter hooks because the function uses `add_filter()`. But personally, if it's a filter hook, I'd always use `add_filter()` to remind myself that it's a filter and it needs something to be returned. And do you still need help with constructing the hook callback?

Comment: Hey Sally. Sorry, I kinda checked out after you helped me with this (I also don't check my email regularly). I'm good for now. Thank you so much. As I am an intern at my company and the only developer here, I was really hoping there would be better wordpress documentation. I feel things aren't so clear sometimes. Happy New Year!